# Select records from n1 to n2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have, for example, 10.000 records in my table. Every time I execute the query I get the page number `n` as a parameter. And I have to select records from `n` to `n*100`, which satisfy some complicated condition. I also use `ORDER BY`, so I can't keep the `PrimaryKey` of the last element and select top `n` records using the primary key. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you're asking how to implement paging with a page size of `100`?

Comment: Yes ))). The problem is OrderBy. if not using it, I am able to implement paging.

Comment: Which database are you using and how are you accessing it?  Although you can do this in SQL, it is probably better done at the application level.  For instance, in Excel/VBA, you can set up the SQL Connection to allow result set to move forward and backward.

Comment: sql server 2008, I retagged my question. I connect to the DB from c#, .Net 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the value of From and To parameter in following query on basis of Page calculation.

```
WITH NumberedMyTable AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        MyTable
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    NumberedMyTable
WHERE
    RowNumber BETWEEN @From AND @To
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @n int
set @n=2

with my_query as(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) as ID, * 
    from sys.tables
)
select * 
from my_query
where ID >=@n and ID<=(@n*10)
```